# Is there a limitation to how many devices one test account on Google Play can install?

Tags: android, testing, google-play, google-play-console

I am using the internal test track on Google Play to test my app. Are there any issues with using the same Google account on fifty different devices for testing the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a limit on the number of devices. Only on the number of accounts.